# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send') (Discord.js V14)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Can someone please explain why its not sending the message?

Im currently testing smth so when you say ">send", My bot sends a message to a channel:

```
if (msg.content === prefix + "send") {
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1137720568850956300');
        channel.send('test succes');
    
    }
```

the `1137720568850956300` is my channel id, but i keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
```

Trust me its the correct id (i doubled checked) and idk why its not working

what surprises me is that i copy and pasted it from the [discord.js guide thinking it would work](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel) but it doesnt. if you really want it heres my full code:

```js
const {
  Events,
  EmbedBuilder,
  Client,
  GatewayIntentBits,
} = require('discord.js');
const greeting = [
  'yo wsp',
  'hi',
  'hello muthafucka',
  'stfu and talk with other people',
];
const lolo = greeting[Math.floor(Math.random() * greeting.length)];
const prefix = '>';
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
});
const EmbedReply = {
  title: 'Do not ping this person.',
  description: '  hes ded because of the pings already ',
  color: '10038562',

  footer: {
    text: 'Current version: 0.0.1',
    icon_url:
      'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1141734104543539220/1141750630763987015/pooperson.jpg',
  },
};

module.exports = {
  name: Events.MessageCreate,
  once: false,
  execute(msg) {
    if (msg.content === '<@1140642830302335098>') {
      msg.reply(`${lolo}`);
    }

    if (msg.content === '<@1089518964360609792>') {
      msg.reply({ content: `<@${msg.author.id}>`, embeds: [EmbedReply] });
    }

    if (msg.content === prefix + 'test') {
      msg.reply('test succesful');
    }

    if (msg.content === prefix + 'send') {
      const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1137720568850956300');
      channel.send('test succes');
    }
  },
};
```

thanks in advance :D

Comment: btw everything else works except that so yeah

Comment: oh shit it bugged

Comment: because `client.channels.cache.get('1137720568850956300');` obviously returns undefined ...

Comment: @derpirscher why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you instantiate a new `client` and it's not the one logged in and listening to the `MessageCreate` event. You will need to remove that and get the client from the `msg` variable:

```js
const { Events } = require('discord.js');
const greeting = [
  'yo wsp',
  'hi',
  'hello muthafucka',
  'stfu and talk with other people',
];
const prefix = '>';

const EmbedReply = {
  title: 'Do not ping this person.',
  description: '  hes ded because of the pings already ',
  color: '10038562',
  footer: {
    text: 'Current version: 0.0.1',
    icon_url:
      'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1141734104543539220/1141750630763987015/pooperson.jpg',
  },
};

module.exports = {
  name: Events.MessageCreate,
  once: false,
  execute(msg) {
    if (msg.content === '<@1140642830302335098>') {
      // you'll also need to move this here or it will be
      // the same message every time
      const lolo = greeting[Math.floor(Math.random() * greeting.length)];

      msg.reply(`${lolo}`);
    }

    if (msg.content === '<@1089518964360609792>') {
      msg.reply({ content: `<@${msg.author.id}>`, embeds: [EmbedReply] });
    }

    if (msg.content === prefix + 'test') {
      msg.reply('test succesful');
    }

    if (msg.content === prefix + 'send') {
      // grab the client here
      const { client } = msg;
      const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1137720568850956300');

      if (!channel) return console.log('Channel not found');

      channel.send('test succes');
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: k i did once again thanks for helping :D

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the channel simply isn't cached at the time. If the result is undefined, try to fetch the channel. If that doesn't work, the error will be more precise about your permissions.

```js
let channel = client.channels.cache.get("id");

if (!channel) {
  try {
    channel = await client.channels.fetch("id");
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

if (channel) channel.send(payload);
```

In order for this to work, your current function **must** have the `async` modifier applied, i.e. `async function(...) {}` or `async (...) => {}`, however you wrote it.